# WordPress issue with get_option and update_option when passing false in $value parameter

Tags: wordpress

I have encountered a strange issue with `get_option` and `update_option`. I was in need of adding an option to `wp_options` table so I used this

`update_option('_option_key_index', false)`, but this never adds a record in the database. But if I pass `update_option('_option_key_index', 0)` the record gets added.

Further inspection of the core function `update_action` reveals something strange. The value `false` is actually being treated as an empty string, whereas `true` is not! So when I am passing `false` for a key which I know does not exist in yet, `get_option` returns an empty string (`$old_value = get_option( $option );`), which when being compared in the following snippet:

```
if ( $value === $old_value )
   return false;
```

always returns `false` and hence no record is being added to the database!

The question is why WordPress is treating the Boolean value `false` as an empty string while it is not same for value `true` ?

Below is a list of values I tried with and the results I got:

```
true: works. Value added is 1
1: works. Value added is 1
false: does not work - No record added
0: works - Value added is 0
'true': works. Value added is true (passed as string)
'false': works. Value added is false (passed as string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PHP casting boolean as a string, `false` become '' (empty string) while `true` become '1' (string).

Since WordPress is PHP-based, you may need to stick to 1/0 or `true`/`false` (as a string) to differentiate a 'boolean'.

Comment: **OR** set a default value for [get_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) and then check the return value. See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/351637